# EasyMock -Unable to mock HTTPServletRequest input stream

Tags: java, junit4, easymock

I am trying to mock a HTTPServletRequest object for JUnit test of a request handler class in my server.
How can i mock the ServletInputStream using EasyMock? I tried

```
HttpServletRequest req = EasyMock.createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(postDataContent.getBytes());
EasyMock.expect( req.getInputStream()).andReturn((ServletInputStream) is);
```

But it is giving an exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletInputStream
 at test.com.comcast.cdvr.handler.ArchivingRequestHandlerTest.testHandlePutRequest(ArchivingRequestHandlerTest.java:76)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ByteArrayInputStream` is not a `ServletInputStream`. By using the cast

```
EasyMock.expect( req.getInputStream()).andReturn((ServletInputStream) is);
```

you can fool the compiler, but not our beloved JVM :-). You need to implement a proper implementation of `ServletInputStream` or use one of the many, many web-testing libraries.

Good luck!

**Update:**

The Exception occuring when mocking ServletInputStream is caused by a missing dependency required by EasyMock. From the [EasyMock documentation page](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html):

> cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2) must be in the classpath to perform class mocking

Comment: i am new to EasyMock. can you give a sample on how can I implement it? I just need to post a dummy string to the request handler class

Comment: As you are already using EasyMock - why don't you use a mock? This should be pretty straight forward because EasyMock will tell you if you did not define the right expectations.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class mocking requires to have cglib and objenesis libraries in the classpath
 at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createProxyFactory(MocksControl.java:140)
 at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:58)i tried mock as the other answer suggested..but it is giving another exception

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it in the same way you mocked `HttpServletRequest`

```
ServletInputStream mockInputStream = EasyMock.createMock(ServletInputStream.class);
EasyMock.expect(req.getInputStream()).andReturn(mockInputStream);
```

Comment: but this is causing another exception. I think the reason is ServletInputStream is an abstract class.

Comment: that's not the problem. Looking at your other messages, it seems you are missing some libs

Comment: i fixed this issue...by extending the ServletInputStream and overriding the read method. From my understanding cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2) comes under PowerMock,right? Use of power mock is strictly forbidden in my company as it has some issues.

Comment: No. cglib and Objenesis are required for EasyMock to mock classes. It has nothing to do with PowerMock